# Compress/uncompress data in memory

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

Using C++ within android (with OpenCV installed)...

I have some data stored in memory (approx 140mb) which I need to save to a file and then send over the internet. What I would like to do is compress it first (putting the compressed data into a different block of memory), then save it. I also need to be able to reverse the process, i.e. load the compressed file into one block of memory and expand into another. I don't care about exactly what type of compression is used. Simplicity of implementation is the most important thing for me.

I am sure similar questions have been asked before, but I'm not confident they will work within the quirky Android NDK environment.

Comment: The zlib implementation is open-source, and I believe it is already part of the android libraries.

Comment: zlib is part of the Android NDK libraries. Link with -lz and include <zlib.h>

Comment: @BitBank: if you put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZLIB is a good choice for generic data compression/decompression. It's included as part of the NDK libraries. The DEFLATE() and INFLATE() functions are widely used and well documented. They can also easily be adjusted for varying speeds and compression ratios. The zlib static library in Android is simply called "z".

In your C/C++ code, add the line:

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

In your Android.mk file, add "-lz" to the LOCAL_LDLIBS line. For example:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz -llog
```